# Unknown provider: listProvider <- list <- listCtrl

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I started an Ionic project, edited it to fit my needs, then suddenly I started getting the error `Unknown provider: listProvider <- list <- listCtrl`. What should I look at to debug this? I'm getting this error when I click on the list view tab. I can provide more information when I get home as I am currently mobile.

UPDATE: Below are the relevant parts of my files.

**My app.js**

```
angular.module('printer', ['ionic', 'printer.controllers'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.list', {
    url: '/list',
    views: {
      'tab-list': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-list.html',
        controller: 'listCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/map');
```

});

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('printer.controllers', [])

.controller('listCtrl', function($scope, list) {

})
```

Comment: Well, remove the argument `list` from your controller. Why do you have that argument in the first place?

Comment: I was editing the started kit, I didn't add anything myself.

Comment: Making random edits without understanding what you're doing won't lead you very far. Read the documentation, or a good book.

Comment: It worked™. Please make that an answer.